# Complex roots in recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was reading brilliant wiki on [recurrence relations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/). It says, if the characterstic polynomial has complex roots. Say $$r=2e^{\pm i\theta}\\\text{where }\theta=\arctan(\sqrt{15})\\\text{for relation }x_n=x_{n-1}-4x_{n-2}$$
Then the solution are given by $$x_n=\alpha2^n\cos{n\theta}+\beta2^n\sin{n\theta}$$
I don't understand why it shouldn't be $$x_n=\alpha2^ne^{in\theta}+\beta2^ne^{-in\theta}$$
or how the two solution are same. Please help.

Comment: `why it shouldn't be` It *could* be that, depending on $x_0,x_1$. But if those are real, then you wouldn't expect $x_n$ to ever be a non-real complex. Take a closer look at how $\,\alpha,\beta\,$ depend on $x_0,x_1$.

Comment: @dxiv I think the two solutions are one and the same just that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are different in both. Not sure how though

Comment: Right, those are not the same $\alpha,\beta$. Write down the formulas for $x_0,x_1$ and it should become obvious.